# Android 3D UI View

Tags: android

I want to display a list of Images in android App. I don't want to use Grid Layout, or ListView Layout.

A custom layout I have selected but I am not able to initiat the development. Custom layout is like--->

if you have or using "Safari Browser" Open it. Go to Top Sites View , it will display a layout of top sites recently visited. Same layout I want to use in my android app to display list of images.

Answer (score 0):

```
mAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(this);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

is this what do you need? check this out,
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List8.html

Comment: this is not same , what I am looking.